# What is wrong in this derivation of centre of mass of hollow hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image: List item]

I am trying another method to find centre of mass for hollow hemisphere.the treatment is as for solid hemisphere but in this case the answer goes wrong i can not found out what is the problem. Please suggest me the actual problem in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Notice as $y$ increases the "height" of the ring element $\Delta y$ underestimates the actual "length" $(AB \rightarrow A'B')$ of the ring element.
This means that for larger $y$ the estimate of mass is too small and so the position of the "centre of mass" found by using this method is going to be smaller than the actual position from the centre of the hemisphere.

[image]

The $R\,d\theta$ method estimates the "length" of a ring element correctly.

Comment: Oh.. thank you .

Comment: But dy approaches 0 so infinitely many such rings should be an accurate approx... which is exactly what op does by using integration. Besides this method works for finding the com of a solid hemisphere.... Can you clear me out? I have the same question. Also its weird as I always thought a hollowed sphere should have 2 radiuses..

Comment: Even when the elements $\Delta y$ become smaller and smaller the fraction $A'B'/AB$ does not become one.